# Filter over dynamically created objects and change their visibility

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a filter to my Todo app that filters by Priority (Low, Mediun, High) I have managed to filter correctly but I can´t seem to change their style.display to 'none' and keep getting this error : script.js:198 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')

```
filterTodo.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const actualSelectedProject = projects.find(
    (project) => project.id === selectedProjectId
  );

  const filteredTodos = actualSelectedProject.todos.filter(
    (todo) => todo.priority === e.target.value
  );
 
  filteredTodos.forEach((filteredTodo) => {
    filteredTodo.style.display = "none";
  });

  console.log(filteredTodos);
});
```

if I change it to filteredTodo.name it changes that value no problem, so I am not sure how to hide this objects.

when choosing 'Low' from the selection console.log prints this: 0: {id: '1659533591483', name: 'Buy milk', date: '10-08-2022', priority: 'Low', complete: false} length: 1 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

so it is filtering correctly, the only problem is I want to remove their visibility

Thanks in advance

Comment: is `filteredTodos` containing dom elements?

Comment: can you update the question with what you got in console.log(filteredTodos)

Comment: @Amaarockz, yes they contain dynamically created Todos, when choosing 'Low' from the selection console.log prints this: 0: {id: '1659533591483', name: 'Buy milk', date: '10-08-2022', priority: 'Low', complete: false}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

so it is filtering correctly, the only problem is I want to remove their visibility

Comment: you can apply/modify style only for dom elements

Comment: toggling visibility in data object doesnt make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work re-rendering each filtered Todo again, here is the code, this way only the filtered todos are rendered instead of trying to hide the rest.

```
//------- Filter Todos------------//
filterTodo.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const todos = document.querySelectorAll(".todo");
  const actualSelectedProject = projects.find(
    (project) => project.id === selectedProjectId
  );

  const filteredTodos = actualSelectedProject.todos.filter(
    (todo) => todo.priority === e.target.value
  );

  if (e.target.value === "No filter") {
    location.reload();
  } else {
    todosContainer.innerHTML = "";
    filteredTodos.forEach((filteredTodo) => {
      const todoElement = document.importNode(todoTemplate.content, true);
      const checkbox = todoElement.querySelector("input");
      checkbox.id = filteredTodo.id;
      checkbox.checked = filteredTodo.complete;
      const label = todoElement.querySelector("label");
      label.htmlFor = filteredTodo.id;
      label.append(filteredTodo.name);
      const para = todoElement.querySelector("p");
      para.id = filteredTodo.id;
      para.textContent = filteredTodo.date;
      const button = todoElement.querySelector("button");
      button.id = filteredTodo.id;
      const del = todoElement.querySelector(".delete");
      del.id = filteredTodo.id;
      const urgent = todoElement.querySelector("ins");
      urgent.id = filteredTodo.id;
      urgent.textContent = filteredTodo.priority;
      if (urgent.textContent === "Low") {
        urgent.classList = "low";
      } else if (urgent.textContent === "Medium") {
        urgent.classList = "medium";
      } else {
        urgent.classList = "high";
      }
      todosContainer.appendChild(todoElement);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```js
const list = element.classList;
list.add("myStyle");
```

instead of apply display in js,
just defined and set attribute in a css class and apply that class to your design with js.
maybe that would work!